# How to initialize values using Set Methods in JAVA, when using Composition?

Tags: java, oop, getter-setter, composition

I was solving OOP (JAVA) practice tasks. While studying the topic of composition, I came across a practice task which is giving me a really hard time. Kindly check my code and suggest a solution. I'll be grateful :)
The practice problem is:

**For each attributes described below, choose appropriate data type. All the attributes of each class should be private and exposed via get/set methods. Also define at least one constructor that allows to initialize 2-3 attributes of object.
**Define a class Course with courseCode and courseTitle instance variable.
Define PhoneNumber class with countryCode, cityCode and lineNumber attributes.
Define a class Address with streetAddress, town, city, country and phoneNumber attributes. The phoneNumber shall be of type PhoneNumber.
Define a class Student with name, email, CNIC, course1, course2 and address attributes. Where course1 and course2 should be of type Course and address shall be of type Address. Define a constructor in Student class that shall take CNIC, name and address only.
Create a StudentTest class. In its main method, create a Student object named student1. Fully initialize its all attributes. CNIC, name and address shall be initialized using constructor. Other attributes shall be initialized using setter methods. All attributes' values shall be given by user. After the object is fully initialized, print all attribute values using get methods.
Make another object student2, assume the user also live at same address as student1. Reuse the address object of student1 to initialze student2 address. You don't need to take attributes from user input for student2 object. Print the values of all instance variables.****

My SCREENSHOTS OF MY CODE:

[StudentTest Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZIpG.png)

[Address Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L64YX.png)

[PhoneNumber Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBqvr.png)

[Course Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnK2f.png)

[Student Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEL7N.png)

THE ERROR I AM GETTING:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NGO6.png)

**A copy of my code:**

**(StudentTest Class)**

```
public class StudentTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber(92, 042, 354);

        Address address = new Address("Street No.502", "HT", "Lahore", "Pakistan", phoneNumber);

        Student student1 = new Student("Muaz", 34603, address);

        student1.setEmail("testEmail@java.com");
        System.out.println(student1.getEmail());


        student1.getCourse1().setCourseCode(101);
        student1.getCourse1().setCourseTitle("OOP");

        student1.getCourse2().setCourseCode(102);
        student1.getCourse2().setCourseTitle("EMO");

        System.out.println(student1.getCourse1().getCourseCode());
        System.out.println(student1.getCourse1().getCourseTitle());
        System.out.println(student1.getCourse2().getCourseCode());
        System.out.println(student1.getCourse2().getCourseTitle());



    }
}
```

**(Student Class)**

```
public class Student {
    //Variables
    private String name;
    private int cnic;
    private Address address;
    private String email;
    private Course course1;
    private Course course2;

    //Constructor
    public Student(String name, int cnic, Address address){ setName(name); setCnic(cnic); setAddress(address); }

    //Set and Get Methods
    public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public void setCnic(int cnic){ this.cnic = cnic; }
    public int getCnic(){ return cnic; }
    public void setAddress(Address address){ this.address = address; }
    public Address getAddress(){ return address; }
    public void setEmail(String email){ this.email = email; }
    public String getEmail(){ return email; }
    public void setCourse1(Course course1){ this.course1 = course1; }
    public Course getCourse1(){ return course1; }
    public void setCourse2(Course course2){ this.course2 = course2; }
    public Course getCourse2(){ return course2; }
}
```

**(Address Class)**

```
public class Address {

    private String streetAddress;
    private String town;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    public Address(String streetAddress, String town, String city, String country, PhoneNumber phoneNumber){
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.town = town;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

**(PhoneNumber Class)**

```
public class PhoneNumber {

    private int countryCode;
    private int cityCode;
    private int lineNumber;

    public PhoneNumber(int countryCode, int cityCode, int lineNumber){
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.cityCode = cityCode;
        this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    }
}
```

**(Course Class)**

```
public class Course {

    private int courseCode;
    private String courseTitle;

    public void setCourseCode(int courseCode){
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }
    public int getCourseCode(){
        return courseCode;
    }
    public void setCourseTitle(String courseTitle){
        this.courseTitle = courseTitle;
    }
    public String getCourseTitle(){
        return courseTitle;
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StudentTest.main(StudentTest.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow(SO). Just so you know, paste your codes and errors in your questions instead of adding screenshots to the question. That way, anyone from SO will be able to check it out themselves.

Comment: Please add your code to your question instead of posting screenshots

Comment: You need to initialize course1 and course2 to non-null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can gather from your screenshots, do the following to remove the `NullPointerException` error:

Initialize the variable `course1` as `private Course course1 = new Course()` in your `Student.java` class. Do the same for `course2`.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
But can you please explain the logic behind that? As per my understanding course1 and course2 are Course type variables, and both of them refer to courseCode and courseTitle. So shouldn't we initialize courseCode and courseTitle directly?

Comment: You should initialize every variable in their each class to prevent bugs. This link will tell you the importance of initializing a variable:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223862/how-important-is-to-initialize-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

It appears you havent set a value for Course1. So you are trying to retrieve a value that doesn't exist.

You should call

```
Course course1 = new Course();
student1.setCourse1(course1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) But can you please explain the logic behind that? As per my understanding course1 and course2 are Course type variables, and both of them refer to courseCode and courseTitle. So shouldn't we initialize courseCode and courseTitle directly?

Comment: courseCode and courseTitle belong to the Course class. you can't initialise variables of a class without first initialising the enclosing class.